# How to merge these two formulas into single fomula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to merge these two formulas into the single formula. I have tried but its not working.

Your help will be much appreciated.

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(trim(Sheet1!A1:E)))
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(trim(Sheet2!A2:E)))
```

What i have tried is:

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(trim(Sheet1!A1:E);trim(Sheet2!A2:E)))
```

and it throws an error

Comment: What did you try that was not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit unclear of the scope but could you try:

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(trim({Sheet1!A1:E;Sheet2!A2:E})))
```

Comment: I was exactly looking for this Thank you, but it adds empty row when 2nd sheet data starts.

Comment: wrap it in a query: =QUERY(ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(trim({Sheet1!A1:E;Sheet2!A2:E}))),"Select * Where Col1!=''")

Comment: Thank you very much just last thing if it does not bother you. I want to keep note that which entry is from Sheet1 and which is from Sheet2. How to maintain this thing I have added some addtion in formula but throws an error: `=QUERY(ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(trim({
{Sheet1!A1:E,"employee1"&Sheet1!Z2:Z};
{Sheet2!A2:E,"employee2"&Sheet2!Z2:Z}
}))),"Select * Where Col1!=''")` To keep separate column whhich shows data is from which sheet

Comment: =QUERY(ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(trim({{Shaheer!A1:E,{"Employee";"employee1"&Shaheer!Z2:Z}}; {Ahsaan!A2:E,"employee1"&Ahsaan!Z2:Z}}))),"Select * Where Col1 IS NOT NULL")